# dump all exceptions on heap with windbg. What is System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallback and System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallback?

Tags: asp.net, windbg

When I am investigating the heap, looking at exceptions, under/after a crash with windbg, I always get listed these three,

- System.ExecutionEngineException
- System.StackOverflowException
- System.OutOfMemoryException

And I know why they are there. It makes sense. But every time I do these dumps, I see these two hanging on the list,

- System.Text.DecoderExceptionFallback
- System.Text.EncoderExceptionFallback

I have always neglected these two. But why is the two on the heap? I have tried to sniff up some info, but I can not seem to find anything usefull. Maybe someone here can tell me why they are on the heap? I have read about the classes on MSDN, but this does not give me anything. I do not think that they, after what I have read on MSDN, are important like the first three. But maybe they are?

Please fill me in :)

Comment: What does "the two twins that belongs to the city" mean?

Comment: Sorry. I have removed phrase. It is a metaphor like "every xx has it/them". Because, every heap dump I have listed have had these two exceptions.

Comment: @mslot, why do we always get System.StackOverflowException, it's not clear to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not exceptions, they just happen to have the word "Exception" in the type name. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoderexceptionfallback.aspx.

Unfortunately SOS doesn't support listing of all instances derived from a specific type, so there's no accurate way to dump all the actual exceptions on the heap. I.e. you will often see false positives.

Comment: Well that answered it :) Thanks Brian!!